# Qt: Динамическое управление видимостью пользовательских элементов в зависимости от некоторого параметра

Tags: qt

Дано:
Приложение на Qt с многочисленными кнопками `QPushButton`, c контекстными `QMenu`, привязанными к многочисленным `QTableView`, к которому прицеплены элементы `QAction`,  которых тоже много, и видимость которых зависит от контекста  QTableView. Все это прекрасно работало.

Однако возникла необходимость управлять видимостью всех этих элементов от типа пользователя, который определяется в момент запуска программы.

Вопрос, как это проще сделать с минимальными изменениями в исходной программе ?

Пока единственное, что я вижу - это сделать несколько списков по числу типов пользователей и в конструкторе заранее распихивать управляющие элементы по этим спискам. И далее анализировать принадлежность к этим спискам, когда потребуется управлять видимостью элемента с помощью функции `setVisible(true/false)`, которая есть у `QPushButton` и `QAction`. Однако беда в том, у них нет общего предка, с функцией `setVisible`. Очень бы не хотелось создавать несколько раздельных списков для `QPushButton` и `QAction`. Нет в Qt более простых средств для решения этой проблемы ?

Comment: `QSettings Class` ?

Comment: @S. Nick, спасибо, сейчас гляну. Но я не спец в Qt и использую его очень редко. Не могли Вы сократить область поиска и сказать куда смотреть в QSettings

Comment: `QSettings Class` - обеспечивает постоянные независимые от платформы настройки приложения.   https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html

Comment: @S. Nick, посмотрел - не, не то :). Проблема не в сохранении настроек, а том, что управление пользовательским элементами раскидано по всему коду.

Comment: Никогда не говори «никогда»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно устанавливать свойство через [`QObject::setProperty ()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setProperty):

```
  action->setProperty("visible", false)
  widget->setProperty("visible", false)
```

Comment: Вот похоже, то что может немного облегчить мою нелегкую долю :). Сейчас попробую.

Comment: visible не освобождает занимаемую виджетом облать.. надо написать несколько стейтов для формы и менять стейт.

Comment: @eri, не особо понял, что тебе с `visible` не нравится...

Comment: @Fat-Zer https://sun9-21.userapi.com/vtAElYsjgT_MZ0Cy9ZCF4dfRvWR91in_LztjRQ/_04VxujOQWo.jpg  вот внизу DialogButtonBox { спейсер, видимая кнопка, невидимая кнопка , видимая кнопка }

Comment: @eri, это квирк `QDialogButtonBox`... в нормальном виджете с лейаутами всё будет без сюрпризов...

Comment: Ну както не хочется держать в голове что поедет - что не поедет) разбить на блоки, блоки на стейты - заодно и прикольные транзишны заработают!

Comment: @eri, кстати, с `QDialogButtonBox` УМВР тоже: https://dpaste.com/HQ8CETV23 ...  https://i.imgur.com/d04H1Jq.gif

Comment: Блин, совсем голова не варит)) у меня то QML

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо за помощь, я отмечаю Ваш ответ, как решение :). Однако, я удивлен, что QT нет удобного способа обхода всех управляющих элементов в окне и нет механизма привязки к ним дополнительной информации, как  в с#.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, дык ты об этом и не спрашивал... произвольные данные можно привязать к виджету через тот же `setProperty()`... а обойти всех детей через `QObject::findChildren()`... но это относительно маргинальные практики и не вижу, как они с твоей проблемой связаны...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, за setProperty() огромное спасибо, с Qt приходится иметь дело редко и я об этом не знал. Вы мне сильно помогли